# В чем разница между обычным программированием и программированием с использованием Spring?

Tags: java, spring, ооп, зависимости

Я понимаю как можно использовать Spring, но я до сих пор не могу понять то, о чём везде так пишут: "Мы разрываем жёсткую связку между классами" и т.д., и т.п.

Но ведь мы и так жёстко всё прописываем либо в аннотациях, либо в `*.xml`, да и к тому же в `Main`, когда пишем что-то вида:

```
Cat cat = context.getBean(Cat.class);
Dog dog = (Dog) context.getBean("dog");
Parrot parrot = context.getBean("parrot-kesha", Parrot.class);
```

Мы ведь и так тут всё жёстко прописали.

Также, Spring использует интерфейсы для ухода от жёсткой зависимости между классами. Тогда что мне мешает без Spring сделать интерфейс `IAnimals` и в нём метод `void voice();`,

а потом, просто сделать:

```
class Cat implements IAnimals {
    public void voice() {
        System.out.print("myau");
}}

class Dog implements IAnimals {
    public void voice() {
        System.out.print("gav");
}}

class Parrot implements IAnimals {
    public void voice() {
        System.out.print("kesha");
}}
```

Вот эту разницу между обычным программированием и программированием с использованием Spring я не могу понять.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем использовать Spring?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428719/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-spring)

Comment: Чтобы по-настоящему понять DI/IoC нужно столкнуться с проблемами, для решения которых они были придуманы. Облысев на поддержке  проекта из сотен тысяч строк кода, разрабатываемого десятками программистов в течении десятка лет, начинаешь очень хорошо понимать все архитектурные шаблоны. А до этого, сколько не читай умных книжек, будет казаться, что это надуманные сложности.

Comment: Видимо, да. До Spring надо дорости, правда, когда необходимо на новом месте, в проме, сразу разбираться с такой технологией с 0, лучше знать о ней побольше)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам реальный пример. Отправка sms на тестовом сервере и на рабочем. В коде который отправляет sms работаем с интерфейсом, а реализацию spring подставляет в зависимости от сервера. Если понадобится отправлять sms сообщение через другой сервис просто добавим новую реализацию, и не будем переписывать весь код, откуда отправляется sms.

```
interface SmsService {
    void send(String to, String message);
}

@Service
@Profile("development")
class DevelopmentSmsService implements SmsService  {
    public void send(String to, String message) {
        // печать сообщения в лог
    }
}

@Service
@Profile("production")
class ProductionSmsService implements SmsService  {
    public void send(String to, String message) {
        // отправка сообщения через API нужного сервиса
    }
}

@Service
class AnotherService {

    @Autowired
    SmsService smsService;

    public test() {
        // что-то делаем
        // отправляем sms через интерфейс, не заботясь о подробностях
        smsService.send(to, message);
    }
}
```

Вы рассматриваете слишком простые пример, где можно спокойно обойтись и без внедрения зависимостей. Но если бы у вас был проект на сотню тысяч классов, где один какой-нибудь `UserRepository` используется тысячу раз по всему проекту, вы бы поняли как это круто что spring подставил везде его реализацию вместо вас.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, он более-менее пододвинул меня к пониманию данной технологии.

Answer (score 1):

Жесткая или не жесткая определяется тем, как вы будете использовать `IAnimals`. Для чего вы создали интерфейс? Для того чтобы иметь классы, которые его имплементируют. Если у вас несколько имплементаций, а вам нужна конкретная имплементация, то вы используете [паттерн метода фактора](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) или [абстрактного фактора](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) для создания экземпляра класса, который имплементирует этот интерфейс.

Таким образом вы можете внедрять нежесткую связь в другие классы без использования Spring.

У вас нет зависимостей между классами. Проблема появляется если вы будете устанавливать связи между объектами, и если эти связи должны быть нежесткие то вам всегда нужно четко знать где и когда, использовать и какую имплементацию. В общем если таких связей очень много, то вы будете морочить себе голову решая подобные проблемы. В конце концов вы поймете, что вам нужен Spring или какой нибудь другой контейнер, где вы будете определять зависимости с помощью конфигурации, независимо от кода их используемого.

Более того, поскольку Spring берет на себя проблему создания бинов, то он еще и занимается менежментом. Что дает возможность интегрироваться в другие фреймворки.

Answer (score 0):

Основная фича Spring это его DI контейнер. Мы можем внедрять зависимости в бины, не задавая жестко тип. Вот Вы привели пример с интерфейсом Animal. Давайте разовьем немного тему. Допустим мы имеем вет. клинику и можем заставлять "говорить" любое животное. При этом нам абсолютно не важно какое это будет животное. Таким образом мы можем написать логику извлечения звука из животных один раз, а самих животных придумывать по ходу пьесы. И не придется править код вет. клиники, а лишь добавлять новых и новых Animal.

```
@Component
public class Clinic {

    private final List<Animal> animals;

    @Autowired //ЕМНИП, в крайних версиях, даже этого делать уже не нужно
    public Clinic(List<Animal> animals) {
        this.animals = animal;
    }

    public void doVoice() {
        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            animal.voice();
        }
    }
}

public interface Animal {
    void voice();   
}

@Component
public Cat implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void voice() {
        System.out.print("myau");
    }
}

@Component
public Dog implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void voice() {
        System.out.print("gav");
    }
}
```

По поводу того, что мы в Spring все-равно жестко все задаем. Посмею с Вами не согласится. Да, в xml мы описывали бины, рассказывая Spring-у кто они, и что они. Теперь же Spring, при помощи аннотаций, сам может разобраться кто есть кто.

Spring это уже не просто очередной фреймворк, это, можно сказать, промышленный стандарт.

Советую к прочтению "Spring In Action" Крэйга Уолша, очень доступно товарищ объясняет.

Comment: Только недавно добрался до этой книжки. В нулевой главе как раз есть краткий с примерами на пальцах обзор спринга.

Comment: Это с натяжкой можно назвать основной фичей Спринг)) да они там повсюду, но это просто di, иначе зачем тогда guice и dagger

Comment: @zolt, за книгу спасибо, почитаю, но в вашем примере, я совершенно не увидел ничего особого по SPring. 
Так как он работает в стандартной программе, если убрать аннотации.